# How to redirect to link using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In razor view I created GET method which updates the data into database, but the thing is when the database is update I am not able to redirect to the respective View.The Following code is of Ajax and Jquery

```
 $("#changeDate").click(function () {

                var startDate = $("#StartDate").val();
                var startTime = $("#StartTime").val();

                var date = startDate + ' ' + startTime;

                event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/Contracts/UpdateStartDateTime",
                        data: {
                            id: @Model.Id,
                            NewStartDateTime: date
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //alert(erro.data)
                        }
                    });
            });
```

and my MVC controller code is:

```
 [HttpGet]
        //[ValidateInput(false)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateStartDateTime(int id, DateTime NewStartDateTime)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = UserManager.FindById(CurrentUserId);
                var workOrder = await _workOrderService.GetForUserAsync(id, CurrentUserId);
                if (workOrder == null || workOrder.Status == WorkOrderStatus.Completed)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                if (workOrder.UserId != user.Id)
                {
                    throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized access");
                }

                var workOrderCategory = await _workOrderCategoryService.GetAsync(workOrder.WorkOrderCategoryId);
                var thisWorkHours = new DateTime(workOrderCategory.AllotedTime).TimeOfDay;
                var NewEndDateTime = NewStartDateTime.Add(thisWorkHours);

                var result = await _contractService.UpdateStartDateTime(workOrder.Id, NewStartDateTime, NewEndDateTime);

                //TODO: check execption

                return RedirectToAction("edit", "contracts", new { id = workOrder.Id});

            }
```

How can I solve this. I have seen to many solution but never found for this.

Comment: with ajax request, you cant redirect via controller. it returns what ever you return. . and check your network tab for whats in response, or use console.log(data) in success to see in console

Comment: Try to check by changing the parameter type in controller method, from `DateTime` to 'string'

Comment: If you want a redirect then why are you using AJAX?  Why not just post the information using a conventional form?